# Trace A Tree For the Recursion

Tags: algorithm

I am feeling difficulty in tracing the tree for the following code ,can anyone please help me out ?
I need to see only recursion tree for the function .

```
private void helper(List<String> allIpAdreess, String s, int buildPointer, int[] path, int segment) {
        if(buildPointer==s.length()&&segment==4) allIpAdreess.add(path[0]+"."+path[1]+"."+path[3]+"."+path[4]);
        else if(buildPointer==s.length()||segment==4) {
            return;
        }

        for(int len=1;len<=3&&len+buildPointer<s.length();len++) {
            String takeSnapshot=s.substring(buildPointer, buildPointer+len);
            helper(allIpAdreess,s,buildPointer+len,path,segment+1);
        }


    }
```

want to see the recursion tree for the i/p s=2551511135

```
helper(allIpAdreess,s,0,path,0);
```

Comment: Did you tried using Debugger?

Comment: Yes , answer is correct but can't figure how  the tree is generated